# start Cucumber runner class from another class in Java

Tags: java, cucumber

At the moment I am trying a few things with cucumber testing in combination with selenium and Java.

Now my question is:

Is it possible to start the RunCucumber class from another class ?

So far I have written this class to start Cucumber from Eclipse :

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
    plugin = {"pretty","json:target/json/jsonoutPretty.json"},
    features={"src/main/resources/FeatureFiles"},

)
public class RunCucumber{

}
```

Now i want to start this RunCucumber Class from another.
Something like this:

```
public class startTests {

    public void startRunCucumber(){

        run(RunCucumber.class);
    }

}
```

Is it somehow possible to achive that ?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: for example the generated JSON file is only available at the very beginning and at the very end of the runtime of the class, caused by the cucumber options. During the runtime the JSON file is empty. So it is not possible to run all tests, and upload the JSON Report (e.g to a REST Service) in one run. So I am trying to upload the JSON results before the Cucumber class runs. Therefore I created another class which should upload the JSON file and run the cucumber tests afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible. You can run the main method used for the command line version of Cucumber.

Invoke `cucumber.api.cli.Main.main()` from your class.

Comment: `Got no path to feature directory or feature file`   
`0 Scenarios`   
`0 Steps`   
`0m0,000s`    
thank you for your help !    
If i try to invoke this, it doesnt find my feature files anymore.. any solutions ?

Comment: Yes, set the path in the argument to the call. I don't have any example handy but please take a look at https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton/blob/master/build.xml and especially lines 61 - 63. It may be sufficient for you to find the arguments you need to set in the array you pass to the main() method